# Variable matrix index and row/column as indices in a single function argument

Tags: r

How to handle a variable matrix index and row/column as indices in a single function argument?

```
m <- matrix(1:9, 3)

fn <- function(m, subsetArg) {
  stopifnot(m[subsetArg] == 6)
}
```

I'd like to be able to use both situations:

```
a <- matrix(FALSE, 3, 3)
a[2,3] <- TRUE
# yielding
# F F F
# F F T
# F F F
fn(m, subsetArgument = a)  # works
```

and

```
fn(m, subsetArgument = tuple(2,3))  # <- does not work logically
```

Note that I would also be after using a range, for example `tuple(2, 1:3)`

I understand this could be done very explicitly by testing for either 1 or 2 variables given, but I feel there might be an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

Just slurp all the arguments up and pass them into a call to `[`:

```
fn <- function(...) {
  stopifnot(do.call(`[`, list(...)) == 6)
}
```

Everything in R is a function, including subsetting :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can subset a matrix using an integer matrix. For example, instead of

```
m <- matrix(1:9, 3)

fn <- function(m, subsetArg) {
  (m[subsetArg])
}

a <- matrix(FALSE, 3, 3)
a[2,3] <- TRUE
fn(m,subsetArg=a)
```

You could simply write:

```
n <- matrix(ncol=2, byrow=TRUE, c(2,3))
m[n]
```

Which would also work in your function, and returns the same result:

```
fn(m,subsetArg=n)
```

If you create your index matrix correct you can get the result that you're looking for in the tuple example:

```
n.tuple <- as.matrix(expand.grid(x=2, y=1:3))
m[n.tuple]
```

Of course you could write a tuple function which does it for you, which would work as expected:

```
tuple <- function(x,y) {
  as.matrix(expand.grid(x=x, y=y))
}

fn(m, subsetArg = tuple(2,3)) # 8 
fn(m, subsetArg = tuple(2,1:3)) # 2 5 8
```